# Printing indicator does not appear in Ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: printing, indicator, 14.04

After some update printing indicator does not appear when I print.

To view and stop printing tasks I have to go to System Settings -> Printers.

How to return it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug has been fixed in the package `0.1.7+14.04.20140527-0ubuntu1`.

[The bug link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicators-client/+bug/1304434)